# Deserialize xml list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

```
             <ns2:dni>
                <ns2:tipoDocumento>
                    <ns2:pais>
                        <ns2:codigo>COL</ns2:codigo>
                        <ns2:nombre>Colombia</ns2:nombre>
                    </ns2:pais>
                    <ns2:codigo>CC</ns2:codigo>
                </ns2:tipoDocumento>
                <ns2:numero>1144040396</ns2:numero>
                <ns2:principal>true</ns2:principal>
                <ns2:campoExtension>
                    <ns2:clave>CIUDAD_DCTO</ns2:clave>
                    <ns2:valor>76001</ns2:valor>
                </ns2:campoExtension>
                <ns2:campoExtension>
                    <ns2:clave>DEPARTAMENTO_DCTO</ns2:clave>
                    <ns2:valor>76</ns2:valor>
                </ns2:campoExtension>
                <ns2:campoExtension>
                    <ns2:clave>PAIS_DCTO</ns2:clave>
                    <ns2:valor>COL</ns2:valor>
                </ns2:campoExtension>
                <ns2:campoExtension>
                    <ns2:clave>LUGAR_EXPEDICION</ns2:clave>
                    <ns2:valor>CALI</ns2:valor>
                </ns2:campoExtension>
            </ns2:dni>
```

So im having problems deserializing this xml document so far i've managed to deserialize "tipoDocumento", "numero", and "principal" correctly, problem is when it reaches the "campoExtension" objects, as you can probably see they're not encapsulated in an object just for them and if i try to create a list in the model it stays empty after deserialization, this is what i get:

```
         "dni": {
            "tipoDocumento": {
                "pais": {
                    "codigo": "COL",
                    "nombre": "Colombia"
                },
                "codigo": "CC"
            },
            "numero": "1144040396",
            "principal": true,
            "campoExtension": []
        }
```

and yes it's a json because im turning it into a c# object so i can serialize with newstonsoft after. please help.

this is my Dni Class:

```
public class Dni
{
    public TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
    public string numero;
    public bool principal;
    public CampoExtension[] campoExtension;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So i found the solution what i did was update my dni class to the following:

```
[XmlRoot("dni")]
public class Dni
{
    public TipoDocumento tipoDocumento;
    public string numero;
    public bool principal;

    [XmlElement("campoExtension")]
    public List<CampoExtension> campoExtension;
}
```

now my json looks like this:

```
       "dni": {
            "tipoDocumento": {
                "pais": {
                    "codigo": "COL",
                    "nombre": "Colombia"
                },
                "codigo": "CC"
            },
            "numero": "1144040396",
            "principal": true,
            "campoExtension": [
                {
                    "clave": "CIUDAD_DCTO",
                    "valor": "76001"
                },
                {
                    "clave": "DEPARTAMENTO_DCTO",
                    "valor": "76"
                },
                {
                    "clave": "PAIS_DCTO",
                    "valor": "COL"
                },
                {
                    "clave": "LUGAR_EXPEDICION",
                    "valor": "CALI"
                }
            ]
        },
```